# Postman collection run async

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I noticed the iteration is run in sequence.

Is async running supported in postman?

For example:

1. POST ENDPOINT A
2. POST ENDPOINT B
3. GET endpoint C
4. GET endpoint D

Collection One
Run iteration 5, for 1,2,3,4

Collection Two
Run iteration 10, for 1,3,2,4

Each collection has different sequence.

But all collection have to run async, same time.

Please correct me if my understanding of postman collection runner is wrong. I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible by default but I think you can find a workaround for this.

In Postman 8 you can create multiple Runners. You can then use different Environments or Input CSV/JSON files so that different runners run on different iterations.

To create a runner click the runner button down on the right side and then press the tab with the right mouse and duplicate.

Another option could be to start Postman collection runner with Newman from CLI or from Nodejs or python code.